# Dynamic bindings in Django template

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

What is the idiomatic way to create dynamic bindings in a Django template?  For example, I have a template that has a list of items along the left.  This list is bound to a model in my view context and displayed with a `{% for %}` loop

On the right, is a form that is supposed to display the values of the selected row in the table on the left.

When the user clicks on a row in my table, I want the form on the right to change to reflect the new values of the selected row.  I cannot seem to find any easy way to do this in Django without submitting a form, which seems counterintuitive OR creating one form for every row in my list and then just showing / hiding the form in question (which also seems undesirable.)

Comment: It sounds like you're going to need something like AngularJS - https://www.angularjs.org/ - to handle that. There's a bit of a learning curve if you've never used it, but it is quite powerful.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid you'd say that.  I'm pretty versed in Angular, so thats no problem.  Just curious if that would be overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a template question. Templates are rendered before they ever get to the browser, so there is quite simply no such thing as a dynamic templates in this sense (and, to be clear, this is a consequence of the way the web works, not a limitation of Django).

The only solution is javascript. If you don't want to render everything in hidden forms, then you will need to dynamically request the form items via Ajax in response to row clicks.

Comment: Makes sense.  Just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing obvious functionality in Django itself.  Thank you.